# How to make form.submit in Javascript quote delimit names and values of post data

Tags: javascript, c#, forms, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to submit a programmatically created form using plain Javascript (no JQuery).

Everything works, except the **post data arrives on the server without quotes** (which the C# `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` method can't parse).

It **arrives as `token:a987a87f9k`**

But **I want** the data to arrive as `'token':'a987a87f9k'`

**What should I change** in this code?

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("id", "noid");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", url);
form.setAttribute("target", tabName);
form.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");

var field = document.createElement("input");
field.setAttribute("name", 'token');
field.setAttribute("value", AccountService.GetAuthenticationToken());
form.appendChild(field);

document.body.appendChild(form);
window.open('about:blank', tabName);
form.submit();
```

Read server-side:

```
//content = "token:a987a87f9k";
var content = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: How does it *arrive*? What is processing the data on the server side? the default for that form getting posted in the way you've described would be `token=a987a87f9k`. I.e. standard url encoding. Not `token:a987a87f9k`

Comment: On the server the content is the string "token:a987a87f9k", read like so: 
var content = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Comment: So your using Web API? What content-type are you sending your HTTP request with?

Comment: Yes. And all the JS that I have is in the question.

Comment: Your correct to say `token:a987a87f9k` is invalid JSON, but so is `'token':'a987a87f9k'`. A valid JSON object would be `{'token':'a987a87f9k'}`. If your not sending the content type as JSON then it should be in a standard name-value pair format (as I said above). Now I don't know Web API so someone else will have to help here, but something about this doesn't really make sense. There is nothing wrong with the JavaScript, the issue lies server side.

Comment: Ok, if this is how the data is supposed to arrive then I'll just handle it using primitive string operations. Not the best solution but it's only one method in my whole app. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not saying this is the format it should be in. TBH I don't know. What I am saying is that it isn't JSON and it's not `name=value` which is the default for HTTP posts. So I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The form post is sending the data to the server in a "form encoded format" while the server is expecting JSON. Either you change the settings on the server or you uses some technique like this one on the client: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: `name:value` is not form encoded. Form encoded is `name=value`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

Comment: Yes you are right I did not see it correctly. Thanks